# MSMQ Adding a delay on Messages

Tags: msmq

I have a Microsoft Message Queue that gets populated with messages. If there is a problem with the processing of the message, I would like to retry the message, I do not want to retry the message immidiatley.
Is there a way to add a delay to the message in the MSMQ to avoid it being available for a certain amount of time??

The other alternative is to have another queue (A retry queue) and read that queue every 15 minutes, But i would rather not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Poison Message Handling" ( even if its not the message fault, but an temporary environment problem ).

There are lots of articles on that. Here are some:

[Poison Message Handling in MSMQ 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751472.aspx)
[Poison Message Handling in MSMQ 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395218.aspx)
[Surviving poison messages in MSMQ](http://www.cogin.com/articles/SurvivingPoisonMessages.php)

In short: you have to move them to a retry queue.

Answer (score 1):

So I've seen some code recently that handles this in the exception logic, the code has a built in retry step that attempts after a delay.  It fails, waits for a specific amount of time, then tries again.

Essentially it recursively tries a set number of times (lengthening the delay each time).  Fairly neat, no reason to have another queue. There is alot of generics and delegates used to execute the methods.  Don't know if something like this could be done or not.  I would suspect you would still want to handle the case of the message not being able to be delivered with another queue though.